# Jenkins with only master node?

Tags: jenkins

The question is:

Am I right stating that Jenkins needs slave nodes only for:

1. Scaling up, if the performance isn't enough:
2. Creating different environments for building several different projects to avoid side-effects on each other.

So, if I have just one project, which is happy with the resources Jenkins master node has, I can carelessly live without any slave nodes with no any side-effects?

Strangely, I haven't been able to find an answer for such simple question in Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is present within Jenkins itself:

> Building on the built-in node can be a security issue. You should set up distributed builds.

So there is a third reason why you should have slave nodes: security. You can find more about this in the [controller isolation doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/controller-isolation/).

But ultimately, this is only a warning. If you are perfectly fine with the risks mentioned and you don't have a functional need for extra nodes, you can run everything on the master node just fine. We used to run only the master node for 2+ years on the Jenkins instance within our intranet before we added in slaves, which are pretty easy to add at any point.